# Facebook login two users

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am working on an app idea and I am curious if a procedure I am thinking of will work.

When a user opens my app he/ she should login with his Facebook credentials and confirms to some permissions. Then a second user should login with his/ her credentials and confirms to the same permissions.

After the two confirmations I would want to save both credentials (and access tokens?) for future use of the app. So every time the app starts, both users get verified with their Facebook accounts and the app gets activated and can be used.

If I understand the Facebook iOS API correctly, it is not possible to login two accounts at once. So how do I:

1. Start app
2. Login user 1
3. Save name and gender for user 1 in a dictionary (do I need to save username and password?)
4. Logout user 1
5. Login user 2
6. Save name and gender for user 2 in a dictionary (do I need to save username and password?)
7. Logout user 2
8. Activate app

Above procedure should run every time an app starts.

I looked at the example app with the iOS SDK (SwitchUser) but I just do not understand where the access tokens are saved and how they can be accessed/ used to accomplish above described procedure.

All the help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to use the Facebook SDK?

Comment: @Wain or should/ could I use something else to make life easier?

Comment: Probably your only option is to use a web view and delete cookies to fully log the user out